# pandas: how to get if column is greater than x select the max of two columns otherwise select mean?

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, data-science, np

I have a df that looks like this and want to add an adj mean that selects the max if one of the two columns (avg or rolling_mean) is 0 otherwise it gets the avg of the two columns.

```
 ID Avg  rolling_mean   adj_mean (goal to have this column)

 0  5    0              5

 1  6    6.3            6.15

 2  5    8              6.5

 3  4    0              4
```

I was able to get the max value of the columns using this code

```
 df["adj_mean"]=df[["Avg", "rolling_mean"]].max(axis=1)
```

but not sure how to add the avg if both values are greater than zero.

Many thanks!

Comment: would be good if you showed your attempts and the error results

Comment: Have you tried anything? This seems rather basic.

Comment: My apologies. Edited to shows where I got stuck on my code. Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the Pandas docs? Or any resource on the subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach can be to treat 0 as `NaN` and then simply calculate the mean

```py
df['adj_mean'] = df.replace({0: np.nan})[["Avg", "rolling_mean"]].mean(axis=1)

Out[1]: 
   rolling_mean  Avg  adj_mean
0           0.0    5      5.00
1           6.3    6      6.15
2           8.0    5      6.50
3           0.0    4      4.00
```

By default, `df.mean()` skips null values. Per the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html):

> **skipna** : bool, default True
>   Exclude NA/null values when computing the result.